# Understanding apply function in R

Tags: r

In R, I've come across the use of the `apply` function. I have looked at the documentation, but want to make sure I understand it correctly.

In the following, `z` is a N*T matrix.

```
> x <- apply(z, 1, var)
```

This code generates a vector of dimension N*1, where element i in `x` is the variance of the i'th row of `z`. Is that correct?

This could also have been written as a for-loop. How would this look?

Comment: Yes your interpretation is correct. The `for` loop would be `for (i in 1:nrow(z)) x[i] <- var(z[i, ])`

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good SO question. (1) yes, except that vectors don't have two dimensions in R ("a vector of length N").

Comment: Learn by trying.  You could have got all your answers in five minutes at the R console.

Comment: another weird close (sorry, "on hold") vote. Is this just a case of a poor set of default close options? This is not seeking debugging code, and it is actually a relatively clear statement.  My reasons for closing (if I had voted that way) would be "too basic" and "insufficient evidence of effort", which are **not** valid close reasons according to the official SO policy ...

Comment: +1 @BenBolker I struggle to see what the problem with this is. (yes it is simple, and basic, but I don't see why this needed to be closed)

Comment: Wow, this created a lot of fuss!

Answer (score -4):

Let's M be matrix

The apply function will just do this

> for(i in 1:nrow(M)){function(M[i,])}

where function can be var (as in your example) or any function.

If you choose as a second argument 2 instead of 1, apply will do the same work on the columns :

> for(i in 1:ncol(M)){function(M[,i])}

Comment: this isn't quite right; you forgot the initialization of a vector and assignment to it.